# C++ constructors functionality

Tags: c++

So I'm doing a final review sheet for my first semester of C++ (and programming in general) and I came across this problem:

> Write a class Person with private members string name, string idNum,
>   in addition to a class Student which inherits from Person with private
>   members string major, int gradYear. Implement the constructors,
>   getters and setters.

I ended up reviewing constructors and decided to watch some YouTube videos to clarify some things and clear up some potential misunderstandings I may have had from class. Now from what I understand, if I were to do this just for the member "name", it should come out looking something like this:

```
class Person
{
    public:
        Person(string z)
        {
            setName(z);
        }
        void setName(string x)
        {
            name = x;
        }
        string getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
    private:
        string name;
};
```

(please let me know if I did this correctly to begin with)

Then I looked at some of my professor's examples and in one of them he wrote the following class:

```
class Shape 
{
    public:
        void setPosition(int x, int y) 
            { 
                xpos = x; ypos = y; 
            }
        double getArea() 
            { 
                return 0; 
            }//return length * width; }
    private:
        int xpos, ypos, name;
};
```

This is where I get confused because if I were to follow this convention, I would not include any setters? Would my answer be functionally the same without the setter, which would then look like this?

Edit: Whoops, the example did have a setter and I must've confused it with the constructor itself unless it's actually both?

```
class Person
{
    public:
        Person(string z)
        {
            setName(z);
        }
        string getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
    private:
        string name;
};
```

I'm aware that the question did specifically ask for the getters as well, but I just want to clear some things up because there seems to be some conflicting information.

Comment: The professor's example *does* have a setter...

Comment: OH you're right. Does it just not have a constructor then?

Comment: Your second example won't work because your constructor calls a function that doesn't exist.

Comment: If you don't provide a constructor you get an implicit default one. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor). Your first example is fine. The choice depends on whether you want to set the value during construction, later, or both.

Comment: Ah yes, have a bunch of data members with a bunch of accessors and mutators, it's not limited to C++, and is a code smell. Objects should do things (possibly with data they own), not simply be clumps of getters and setters for private fields.

Comment: @Storyteller That is all fine and well, but at the heart of each stateful object is data, right? And you need to access it, both to set and get it. (Not necessarily is there a bijective relation between data and accessors -- the vector may hold angle and length but allow setX() -- but the data design will hopefully follow the most common usage and thus often *start* with direct data access.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, No it doesn't. If a design is littered with classes that just carry data around it quickly becomes a pain to work with and maintain. The best approach is to abstract the direct data access completely. Create a person registry (an object that does things) for accessing person data. It's much more flexible and tolerant. When you start thinking in terms of what objects do, rather then what they have, your designs only benefit.

Comment: The professor's `Shape` class -- provided that you show the complete class here -- is funny because there is no way to retrieve its position after creating it, which doesn't make any sense. (The position also is not used for the only operation common to Shapes, `getArea()`), and cannot be accessed by derived classes because the members are private.) It is probably also wrong to not declare `getArea()` virtual because the whole point of such a class is to provide a common interface which will be (re-)implemented by the derived classes which thus can be handled uniformly.

Comment: @StoryTeller And what, exactly, would you store in your registry?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, raw structures, rDB access or whatever.

Comment: @StoryTeller A raw structure is what *I* consider code smell.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, good thing I never pass them around than. I don't have to, I have a registry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of constructors as an instantiater that set member attributes. The difference is that constructors get called exactly once for an object. Consider you have a class with a field that *will not change* - if you write a public setter, this would be incorrect.

Consider the situation of Americans with social security numbers. It is [**awfully rare** to change your SSN](http://www.esia.net/Social_Security_Numbers.htm), so if you were modeling an American (person), you might not include a `set_ssn` method.

```
class American {
  public:
    American(std::string name, std::string ssn) { 
      name_ = name; 
      ssn_ = ssn; 
    }
    void interact() { /* do my living stuff */ }
  private:
    std::string name_;
    std::string ssn_;
};
```

Now you can use this like so:

```
American erip("Elijah", "mysecretssn");
erip.interact();
...
```

If I regularly change my hair color, you could add a `set_hair_color` method to my class.

```
void set_hair_color(const std::string hair_color);
```

and a `std::string hair_color_` to my private members.

Now I could do this:

```
American erip("Elijah", "mysecretssn");
erip.interact();
erip.set_hair_color("black");
erip.set_hair_color("red");
...
```

In summary, you will write setters if things change about your person, but all member functions have access to private variables and can thereby change them. Setters are a way to "publicize" your member variables to the user of your code.

Comment: Use initializer lists please.

Comment: @Jean-BernardJansen OP doesn't understand OOP, so I won't use them for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But just in case I'm misinterpreting something, 

American(std::string name, std::string ssn) { 
      name_ = name; 
      ssn_ = ssn; 
    }

is the constructor, right?

Comment: Got it. I understand constructors better now, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

This is not limited to C++, but general OOP style.

Usually you will have both setters and getters, e.g. *setFirstName(..)* and *getFirstName()*, since you those are states that can change (especially a lastname via marriage) or simply because not all data was available when creating the object, someone made a typo, whatever.

If you have a derived property you will usually only have a getter. In the above example you have a *getArea()* method, a setter doesnt really make any sense, whereas a *setWidth(..)* and *setHeight(..)* obviously do. Another example would be a *getSalutation()* (which could return some combination of title, firstname and lastname).

In some cases, e.g. for dependency injection, just having a setter can also be correct.

Sometimes you dont want any accessors at all. This can be the case for internal variables where setting these may cause inconsistencies or even security concerns. Note however, that by hiding those variables (via private scope) you are pretty much assuming you know best how to deal with every use case.

Comment: I don't like this answer because of the sentence `usually you will have both setters and getters`. Creating getters and setters as a rule in OO is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @erip I know the arguments against accessors. I personally consider a lot of them pretty brain dead and very impractical in the real world. Nevertheless i will add examples where accessors can be the wrong way to go.

Answer (score -1):

No, yours example without setter would look like this:

```
class Person
{
    public:
        Person(string z)
        {
            name = z;
        }
        string getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
    private:
        string name;
};
```

You can't invoke `setName` as you wrote it in question because `setName(String)` function isn't defined.

But if you write it that way you couldn't change name for any instance of person.
Basically when field inside of object (basic type variable, or another object) is set to `private` you can't access it from outside of that object. So by writing `Person` like this you make it immutable - after creation you can't change contents of `Person` instance.

You can consider it as choice:
Either use `public` variables, or `private` with `setField` and `getField` methods.
Basically second option is best, because you can always add some logic to setter - i.e. capitalize letters inside your string, or check if provided value is valid.

In professor's example you've provided there is setter - `void setPosition(int,int)` method, but he didn't wrote constructor, so compilator'll add default parameterless constructor that won't set xpos, nor ypos.

Comment: Please explain to me why it was downvoted. This way I'll also learn sth.